# How to handle multiple routes have same path

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am migrating project from Ruby on Rails to .NET Core, and I am lost on routing part, because path or slug part in url hit multiple controllers. I will explain:

```
LocationController(string path)
http://www.website.com/asia
http://www.website.com/north-america/usa/florida
Path is everything except website, so: asia, north-america/usa/florida

SchoolController(string slug)
http://www.website.com/st-martin-school
http://www.website.com/rene-claudius-school
Slug is everything except website, so: st-martin-school, rene-claudius-school

PageController(string slug)
http://www.website.com/privacy-policy
http://www.website.com/contact
Slug is everything except website, so: privacy-policy, contact
```

I know the solution isnt perfect, but this was decision because of SEO and now i can't change the urls. .NET core app now don't know what endpoint to hit. The routing on Ruby on Rails was different, it went over configured routes from top to down and what endpoint hit first, it was executed. How to solve this issue in .net core? I was reading about Wildcards, but still don't know how to use it.

Thanks for help.

## Solution

Based on responses, It gave me idea of solution by custom constraint. Here it is.

**Create a location constraint to catch all valid locations starting by continent name string:**

```
public class LocationConstraint : IRouteConstraint
    {
        private static readonly string[] continents = { "africa", "asia", "australia", "europe", "north-america", "south-america" };

        public bool Match(HttpContext httpContext, IRouter route, string routeKey, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
            if (values[routeKey] is null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            string routeValue = values[routeKey].ToString();

            if (continents.Contains(routeValue) || continents.Any(c => routeValue.StartsWith(c + "/", System.StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Catch all valid location in LocationController:**

```
[HttpGet("{**path:location}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> List(string path)
        {
```

**Catch all valid static routes in PageController:**

```
[HttpGet("latest")]
...

[HttpGet("privacy-policy")]
...
```

**Catch rest all schools in SchoolController:**

```
[HttpGet("{slug}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Detail(string slug)
        {
```

Comment: You need to have specific routes added to the route table first. Such as route for privacy policy and contact. And then continent routes. There are only a fixed number of continents so you can add special route entry for each of them. The generic routes should be at the last. They will be for schools.

Comment: Can u please show me where to put it and how it will looks like?

Comment: are you using ApiControllers?

Comment: @Anubix PageController(string slug) it will not be compilled in asp.net mvc, pls post the real code

Comment: Thanks for tip, over weekend I solve it with CustomConstraintRoute. Thanks for tips.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by mapping appropriate routes in route table. In ASP.NET Core mapping routes is not allowed if the controller is decorated with [ApiController].

So if you are not using [ApiController] on your controller, following the solution I propose.

Following are the controllers and actions inside them, for example.

```
public class LocationController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get(string path, string country, string city)
    {
        return new JsonResult(new { Path = path, Country = country, City = city });
    }
}

public class SchoolController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get(string slug)
    {
        return new JsonResult(new { Slug = slug });
    }
}

public class PageController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get(string slug)
    {
        return new JsonResult(new { PageSlug = slug });
    }
}
```

Following is the route mapping needed.

```
app.MapControllerRoute("schoolroute", 
                       "/{slug=*-school}", 
                       new { controller = "School", action = "Get" });
app.MapControllerRoute("privacypolicy", 
                       "/{slug=privacy-policy}", 
                       new { controller = "Page", action = "Get" });
app.MapControllerRoute("contact", 
                       "/{slug=contact}", 
                       new { controller = "Page", action = "Slug" });
app.MapControllerRoute("pathroute", 
                       "/{path}/{country}/{city}", 
                       new 
                       { 
                             controller = "Location", 
                             action = "Get", 
                             country = "", 
                             city = "" 
                       });
```

The controller action method signatures, in above solution, may not match with yours. My suggestion is to make appropriate changes in your code if possible. Else share relevant code in the original question and explain the issue you face.